# How to set tableViewHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on menu bar using SWReveaViewController, I did it, Now I change the uitableview'tableHeaderView(not section header view) , But the result not my expect, Why it had a seperator space on the top my tableview, I think it section header? But I don't know how to change it, Please help....
[image: here it is my result]

My code:

```
 let headerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.view.frame.width,height:40))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 47/225, green: 97/225, blue: 76/225, alpha: 1)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Comment: It is working as expected based on tour screenshot and the code you’ve provided. Can you show us an example of your desired outcome?

Comment: Do you have the tableview in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top space above the header is safe area insets. You should change your table view top anchor to its superview.

In storyboard you need to change the top constraint of the tableview.
In storyboard select the tableview and select size inspector.

[image]

Select the top constraint by double clicking. And change the second item from `Safe Area` to `Superview` then change the constant value to 0.

[image]    [image]

And use

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: @chikwongyip select tableview in story board and select size inspector

Comment: I solved it with this code: self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```